# Is "only" here for emphasis?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[image]

Here’s the context where "only’ appears.

Comment: Where's **only**?

Comment: @ Decapitated Soul  Sorry!that’s embarrassing. I’ve edited it.

Comment: "only underscores" is a shortened form of "only serves to underscore" - yes, "only" is emphatic.